# Symfony - setting enum type

Tags: php, symfony, enums, symfony4

In my Symfony project I to define **enum** types for string field:

```
class Log
{

  const TYPE = [
    0 => 'invite',
    1 => 'revoke'
  ];

 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
  * @Assert\NotBlank
  */
 private $type;
}
```

And then in my setter:

```
$newLog->setType(Log::TYPE[0]);
```

Is this the right approach for setting enum types within Symfony or there is perhaps better way to do so?

Comment: Better under what context? Technically, despite performance impacts, one can consider it a better way to use [Discriminator mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) and use specific class names for the enum types eg: `InviteLog extends Log` and `RevokeLog extends Log`.  Another approach would be to follow the [Enum Doctrine cookbook](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/mysql-enums.html#solution-1-mapping-to-varchars)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [myclabs/php-enum](https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum) along with [acelaya/doctrine-enum-type](https://github.com/acelaya/doctrine-enum-type) for integration with Doctrine ORM.

These libs will handle mapping of object to DB type and vide versa.

```
class LogType extends Enum
{
   public const INVITE = 'invite';
   public const REVOKE = 'revoke';
}

class Log
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="php_enum_log_type", nullable=false)
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    */
    private LogType $type;
 }

 $newLog->setType(LogType::INVITE());
```